# Show $\int_0^\infty f\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)\,\frac{\ln x}{x}\,dx=0$ if $f(x)$ is a bounded non-negative function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

> **Lemma**
>
> If $f(x)$ is a bounded non-negative function, then
> \begin{equation}\int_0^\infty f\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)\,\frac{\ln x}{x}\,dx=0\end{equation}

I found this lemma on internet and it seems it will be useful for me to evaluate integral problems in the future. Unfortunately, it's without proof and, *alas*, I don't know how to prove it. Honestly, I am not good at this kind problem. So, I really need your help. I'd be grateful if you could help me to prove it.

**Edit :**

I am really sorry for the additional questions. I want to know why must $f(x)$ be a bounded non-negative function? Could you give an example problem to apply the lemma? Please elaborate your answer. Thank you.

Comment: Any other conditions? Otherwise the integral can be ill-defined.

Comment: If you put $f:=$constant $>0$, your integral is not convergent, in the usual sense.

Comment: For instance, let : f=1 ;

$ \int_a^b \frac{ln(x)}{x}dx =[\frac{ln(x)^2}{2}]_a^b = \frac{ln(b)^2-ln(a)^2}{2}  $

it doesn't converge either for  $ a \rightarrow 0$ nor$ b \rightarrow +\infty$

Comment: For those cases were it works, I'd also like to see an explanation (apart from the formal proof of showing it must equal its negative), maybe a visual reason.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just substitute $u = \frac{1}{x}$ and get

$$\int_\infty^0 f\left(u+\frac{1}{u}\right) \frac{\ln u}{u}\,du.$$

Note the switch of integral limits.

> I want to know why must $f(x)$ be a bounded non-negative function?

It need not be, all you need is that the integral exists, be it as a Lebesgue integral or an improper Riemann integral. Since the factor $\frac{\ln x}{x}$ tends to $0$ for $x\to\infty$ almost fast enough to be integrable, a fairly slow decay of $f$ at infinity is sufficient to guarantee the existence of the integral, e.g. if $\lvert f(t)\rvert \leqslant C\cdot(\log t)^{-(2+\delta)}$ for some positive constants $C$ and $\delta$ (and $f$ is measurable), the integral exists as a Lebesgue integral. Also, the integral exists as a Lebesgue integral if $f$ is Lebesgue-integrable. As an improper Riemann integral, it also exists if $f$ oscillates appropriately, without needing a decreasing amplitude, e.g. for $f = \sin$ or $f = \cos$.

You can relax that condition, if you interpret the integral as

$$\lim_{\varepsilon\searrow 0} \int_{\varepsilon}^{1/\varepsilon} f\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right) \frac{\ln x}{x}\,dx,$$

a principal value integral. Then you only need $f$ to be locally integrable, the substitution shows that these integrals are $0$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$.

Comment: Now a good question could be: which property (ies) f should verify in order to assure the existence of the integral :) ?