# $\int_0^{\infty} A( f(B(x)) ) + C(x) ) dx = \int_0^{\infty} f(x) dx$

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

I was thinking about $\int_0^{\infty} A( f(B(x)) ) + C(x) ) dx = \int_0^{\infty} f(x) dx$

The inspiration came from the following 3 integrals :

> **Lemma**
>
> If $f(x)$ is a bounded non-negative function, then
>   \begin{equation}\int_0^\infty f\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)\,\frac{\ln x}{x}\,dx=0\end{equation}

proved here : [Show $\int_0^\infty f\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)\,\frac{\ln x}{x}\,dx=0$ if $f(x)$ is a bounded non-negative function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1001430/show-int-0-infty-f-leftx-frac1x-right-frac-ln-xx-dx-0-if-fx/1001442#1001442)

and

\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)dx&=\int_{0}^{\infty}f\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)dx+\int_{-\infty}^{0}f\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)dx=\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(2\sinh T)\,e^{T}dT + \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(2\sinh T)\,e^{-T}dT=\\ (collecting\space terms )
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(2\sinh T)\,2\cosh T\,d T=\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\,dx.
\end{align}

as discussed here : [Why is this integral $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} F(f(x)) - F(x) dx = 0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1069871/why-is-this-integral-int-infty-infty-ffx-fx-dx-0)

(or the more general in the link)

And the trivial case valid for $-\infty < y < +\infty$ :

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)dx = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x+y)dx$$

Im intrested in seeing generalizations of this such as

$\int_0^{\infty} A( f(B(x)) ) + C(x) ) dx = \int_0^{\infty} f(x) dx$

or other similar improper integrals.

Comment: Im going to ask a related question soon.